# Should I use equations in a research statement for faculty positions?

Tags: faculty-application, research-statement

I'm writing a research statement for a faculty position. I've divided the statement into small sections discussing past, current work, and future directions. I'm wondering if people often do use equations in the statement about their research?

The research is on machine learning (ML). The target is a mathematics department with an ML opening.

Answer (score 36):

You are asking the wrong question. The right question you should be asking yourself is "How do I best explain what I want to say, to the audience I have identified for the thing I'm writing". You will notice that I'm saying this not with regard to a research statement as part of an application, but in general: This is the advice you should consider for *everything* you write: Identify who your audience is, what they know, what they want to get out of what you are writing for them, and then use that insight to decide *how* you should write.

As for the specific question: Yes, research statements addressed to math departments typically use formulas. That's because that audience is clearly capable to understand these formulas, and will want to see enough detail that it is worth stating them in concise, mathematical notation.

Comment: Thanks. Since you are in the math department, how many pages do they usually write? Is 7 pages too much?

Comment: In [my institution's current job ad](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/190529/should-i-use-equations-in-a-research-statement-for-faculty-positions), we suggest 3-5 pages for a research statement. By the way, it sounds like you might want to apply for this particular opening…!

Comment: @GregMartin wrong link?

Comment: 3-5 pages sounds like a reasonable number.

Comment: I am applying to Ph.D. programs in Optimization/ML this year, and my advisor suggested that I should "put formulas in my research statement to show people the work I have done". However, I find it hard to do in practice since for formulas to make sense you need to define some notations first, which takes a lot of words. Additionally, I cannot explain my research in a sentence if the readers are not familiar with the background, and using words allows me to gross over some details. I wonder if I should still use equations at the cost of conciseness to please the admission committee?

Comment: Sorry, the correct link is https://www.mathjobs.org/jobs/list/20980

Comment: "Identify who your audience is, what they know, what they want to get out of what you are writing for them, and then use that insight to decide how you should write." If your audience is the whole department, then you're right that you need to define notation. If your audience is that part of the department that does things related to what you do, then maybe not. In any case, the other universal truth also applies: "Talk to your adviser about it."